# Вывод переменной в текст Label Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
lbl = Label(exerc, text=("Занятие № ", num))
```

Пытаюсь таким способом вывести переменную но тогда текст выводится вот так: {текст} переменная.
Подскажите способ вывода получше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
lbl = Label(exerc, text=("Занятие № ", num))
```

примените

```
lbl = Label(exerc, text=f"Занятие № {num}")
```

(для Питона 3.6+, иначе `text="Занятие № {}".format(num)`).

---

*Объяснение:*

Невозможно дублировать поведение функции `print()`, в которой возможно задавать множество параметров любого типа.

Конструктор `Label` в параметре `text=` требует  **точно одну строку**.

Значит, когда вы хотите вместе задать например **текст и число**, вы должны эти 2 данные *предложить в виде одной строки.*

f-строка `f"Занятие № {num}"` делает точно это - соединяет текст и чило в одну строку.